# Application.streamingAssetsPath and WebGL build

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

In a project I'm working on I have two json files in the StreamingAssets directory. The script that handles them works perfectly in a Standalone PC build but doesn't work at all in a WebGL one.

I'm getting the "Cannot find file!" message according to the script:

```
    else if (!File.Exists (filePath))
    {
        Debug.LogError ("Cannot find file!"); 
    }
```

I was given the answer to use the WWW class as described in the scripting API on Unity Technologies site at this address: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MyFile");
    public string result = "";
    IEnumerator Example() {
        if (filePath.Contains("://")) {
            WWW www = new WWW(filePath);
            yield return www;
            result = www.text;
        } else
            result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    }
}
```

I would gladly do that but I'm too new at coding and I need some explanations. The first question I have for now is: what is this **"my file"** string in the line

```
    public string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MyFile");
```

What am I supposed to write there? Is it a url? And if it is a url, the url of what?

I would be very grateful is someone could hold my hand and guide me into understanding this! Thank you!

(This is my first question here; I hope I haven't made mistakes as I don't know how this place works yet.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The first question I have for now is: what is this "my file" string in
>   the line

That's supposed to be the name of the file.Although, it is missing it's extension name. You should add that. For example, *.txt*, *.jpg*, *png*....

> What am I supposed to write there? Is it a url? And if it is a url,
>   the url of what?

You are just supposed to write the name of the file with the extension name where *"MyFile"* is.

**Example uses:**

In your Project, you create a folder called "*StreamingAssets*".

Let's say that you have a file named *"Anne.txt"*, and the file is inside the  *"StreamingAssets"*. folder, this should be your path:

```
public string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Anne.txt");
```

---

Now let's say that the "*Anne.txt*" folder is placed in a folder called "*Data*" which is then in the "*StreamingAssets*" folder, it should look like this:  "*StreamingAssets/Data/Anne.txt*".

Your path should be:

```
public string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Data");
filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath , "Anne.txt");
```

That's it. Nothing complicated here. You then use that path string with `WWW`.

Also your  `if (filePath.Contains("://"))` should be `if (filePath.Contains ("://") || filePath.Contains (":///"))`.

**EDIT**

If you have multiple files you want to load, I simplified that function into this so that it takes the file name as parameter.

```
IEnumerator loadStreamingAsset(string fileName)
{
    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, fileName);

    string result;
    if (filePath.Contains("://") || filePath.Contains(":///"))
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(filePath);
        yield return www;
        result = www.text;
    }
    else
        result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
}
```

Now, let's say that you have 3 files called "*Anne.txt*", "*AnotherAnne.txt*" and "*OtherAnne.txt*" placed in the "*StreamingAssets*" folder, you can load them with the code below:

```
StartCoroutine(loadStreamingAsset("Anne.txt"));

StartCoroutine(loadStreamingAsset("AnotherAnne.txt"));

StartCoroutine(loadStreamingAsset("OtherAnne.txt"));
```

Comment: Thank you Programmer (how do we tag users here?). I thought that this "MyFile" was something present in the StreamingAssets folder, but, there are two files in mine. So, what does "MyFile" becomes when there are several files in the StrreamingAssets folder?

Comment: Why "Also your if (filePath.Contains("://")) should be if (filePath.Contains ("://") || filePath.Contains (":///"))."? I mean, why three slashes?

Comment: You use @theusername to reply to user but you don't need to do that under my answer. I will be notified regardless.   If you have multiple files, you have to call WWW multiple times and provide the name of each file to the apth after each one is done loading.For your last question, the file path could be `/` or `//`. That's why both are checked.

Comment: Thank you again. What about "MyFile" in the case of multiple files in the StreamingAssets folder?

Comment: I modified the function so that you can pass in the file name as parameter. Please check the Edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm going to try that; I'll come back with the result. :)

Answer (score -1):

You read from a file folder

You need to read from a server for webgl

WebGl won't let you do that.

Here is the suggestion

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTextBinaryData.html