# What Cause Unity Profiler Graph Too High?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I really need help to figure out what happen in my game. I have try using Unity Profiler when game start. This is editor, But i see the Profiler especially for CPU Usage the graph chart is very high. You can check the picture below.

[image]

[image]

I don't know what cause this like this. But i am sure my game become slow and then sometimes slow in change scene load scene is because the graph is too high

So what could cause this ? What should i do ? What i need to do to reduce the graph to lower.

Thank You

Comment: You are doing something that's costing you 150 bytes each frame. I suggest you need "Deep Profile". You may be able to see what that is

Comment: Could we see what script is that ? How to check what script is that ?

Comment: I believe you can. Enable "Deep Profile" like I said then expand `Update.ScriptRunBehaviourUpdate` and see if the function or script name is mentioned. See [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/profiler-overview-beginners) and [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/introduction-profiler) post for how to use the profiler.

Comment: Is that a big problem costing 150 bytes each frame ?

Comment: No, but if you have that script connected to multiple GameObjects then that would be a problem. Let's say it is attached to a prefab that is instantiated every once and then.

Comment: I have this script : https://imgur.com/a/1QSKy and it instatiated for 50 object each have that's script attacth to gameobject. Is it a problem ? I see that it take 8.6kb in GC Alloc profiler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155472/discussion-between-dennis-liu-and-programmer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **@programmer** discuss solution.

1. Do not do something in update that costing 100 bytes or more, Imagine
   that if you have that script connected to multiple GameObjects then
   that would be a problem. Let's say it is attached to a prefab that
   is instantiated every once and then.
2. Don't use lambda in the Update function. Avoid it at-all in Unity if
   you can.
3. **Edited** : If possible try to avoid using FindIndex search at Update().

That's the suggestion from **@programmer**

For more information support check this :

[Application.streamingAssetsPath and WebGL build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43693213/application-streamingassetspath-and-webgl-build/43695023#43695023)

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager